# Reverse deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split Multiple Columns into Multiple Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678479/split-multiple-columns-into-multiple-rows)

My table look like this

```
accounting | research | sales | operations 
------------------------------------------
         3 |        5 |     6 |          0
```

It is necessary to receive a resultant set with two columns and four lines

```
dname      |        cnt
-----------------------
accounting |          3
research   |          5
sales      |          6
operations |          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator like so:

```
DECLARE @t table (accounting int, research int, sales int, operations int);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(3, 5, 6, 0);

   SELECT dname, cnt
    FROM
    (
       SELECT accounting, research, sales, operations 
       FROM @t
    ) t 
    UNPIVOT
    (
      cnt FOR dname IN (accounting, research, sales, operations )
    ) u
```

### Here is a [live demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81334/unpivot-columns-into-rows)

Here is the standard sql query for doing this, for RDBMS that doesn't support `UNPIVOT` table operator:

```
SELECT dname,
  CASE dname
    WHEN 'accounting' THEN accounting 
    WHEN 'research'   THEN research
    WHEN 'sales'      THEN sales
    WHEN 'operations' THEN operations
  END AS cnt
FROM @t
CROSS JOIN
(
   SELECT 'accounting' dname
   UNION ALL SELECT 'research' 
   UNION ALL SELECT 'sales' 
   UNION ALL SELECT 'operations'
) t2
WHERE dname IS NOT NULL
```

### [Live DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81341/unpivot-columns-into-rows-without-unpivot-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Not all RDBMS have the `UNPIVOT` function, so another way to do this if you do not have the `UNPIVOT` operator is with `UNION ALL`:

```
select 'accounting' dname, IsNull(accounting, 0) cnt
from yourtable
union all
select 'research' dname, IsNull(research, 0) cnt
from yourtable
union all
select 'sales' dname, IsNull(sales, 0) cnt
from yourtable
union all
select 'operations' dname, IsNull(operations, 0) cnt
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a5d4/2)